# CSS Hover Effect not working when an inline style is set

Tags: javascript, css, colors, hover

I've got an H1 element, which from standard has the color white. This element is in my upper navigationbar. When the page is scrolled the navigationbars background color is changed and so is the color of the text. So the text color changes from **white** to **black**. To accomplish this, my javascript just adds an inline style tag to the element setting the **color:black**.

There is also a hover-state defined. When the user hovers over the H1-element, the **color changes to darkorange**. Since the inline style tag is set to black, the CSS property for the color which is set when hovering over it is ignored, better sayed the inline style stands above the CSS property.

How can I solve this problem?

let h1children = document.getElementById('divNavigationContainer').getElementsByTagName('h1');
            let achildren = document.getElementById('divNavigationContainer').getElementsByTagName('a');

```
        if (window.scrollY) {
            document.getElementById('divNavigationContainer').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            document.getElementById('divNavigationContainer').style.borderBottom = '1px solid darkorange';

            for(let i=0;i<h1children.length;i++) {
                h1children[i].style.color = 'black';
            }
            for(let i=0;i<achildren.length;i++) {
                achildren[i].style.color = 'black';
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById('divNavigationContainer').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
            document.getElementById('divNavigationContainer').style.borderBottom = 'none';

            for(let i=0;i<h1children.length;i++) {
                h1children[i].style.color = 'white';
            }
            for(let i=0;i<achildren.length;i++) {
                achildren[i].style.color = 'white';
            }
        }
```

CSS:

```
    .aNavigationObjectText:hover {
        color:darkorange;
     }

    .aNavigationObjectText {
       float: right;
       position: relative;
       cursor: pointer;
       font-family: Arial;
       font-weight: unset;
       font-size: 15px;
       color: white;
       margin-left: 15px;
       margin-right: 15px;
       margin-top: 20px;
       text-decoration: none;
       transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
     }
```

**EDIT**

My problem was solved by a simple **!important** tag!

```
     .aNavigationObjectText:hover {
        color:darkorange !important;
     }
```

Comment: can you post your css code?

Comment: use `!important`

Comment: Can you provide examples of what is going on, what you're expecting, and what you've tried

Comment: yes ^ only `!important` after hovered value in css could save you

Comment: I've edited the question! Thanks for your help so far, I think !important is the key, yes im gonna try it right now :)

Comment: .aNavigationObjectText:hover {
        color:darkorange !important;
     }

Comment: That did it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

*!important* works. Do **NOT** use *!important*! You can search the web for a long list of reasons.

Also it's not a good idea to mix inline CSS and regular CSS. My suggestion is to apply a CSS class to the element instead:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

If you do it this way then your hover style will work without !important.